# Theorem 6.5.13 in Topology and Groupoids by Ronald Brown

Tags: category-theory, axiom-of-choice

The Theorem states

6.5.13 A subcategory $D$ of $C$ is a deformation retract of $C$ if and only if $D$
is a full, representative subcategory of $C$. In fact, if $D$ is a full representative
subcategory of $C$ and if we define $θx = 1_x$ for each object $x$ of $D$, and choose
$θy$ for any other object $y$ of $C$ to be an isomorphism of some $x$ in Ob($D$) with
$y$, then $θ$ determines a deformation retraction $r : C → D$ and a homotopy
$ir ≃ 1 \ rel \ D$, where $i : D → C$ is the inclusion.

This seems to use some notion of choice for arbitrary categories. Is there some formal justification for this (generalization of AoC) or is the theorem only valid for small categories?

Comment: There is something called "axiom of choice for classes" or "class axiom of choice" or various other denominations that allows  you to do that. If you don't accept this, then it's only valid for small categories; and if you don't accept the axiom of choice, then it's not even valid for them. There is a notion of functor that is more appropriate for constructive maths (and probably for "choiceless" maths) for which the theorem holds, it's the notion of anafunctor (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The axiom of choice is indeed talking about sets, which would correspond to small categories. The generalization, which is very often assumed when talking about arbitrary categories, is *global choice* which simply asserts that the class of *all* non-empty sets admit a choice function.

Other than just being the "obvious generalization" of the axiom of choice, the justification is that in any "reasonably definable" model of ZFC (e.g. $L[A]$ or $\mathsf{HOD}[X]$) we have a global choice function definable (with parameters, perhaps).

Once we move to categories which are not locally small either, I guess you'd need to apply to second-order choice principles. Those are, again, straightforward generalizations. Here things get a bit trickier, as things often do when moving to second-order logic. So it will depend on how you formalize your second-order set theory.

Of course, one way to avoid all of this is to use universes.

Comment: Is it really global choice that we need here ? It seems to me that the things we need to choose from can be proper classes, so we need something different than global choice, right ? (of course, this issue goes away with universes too)

Comment: Max, if you work with universes, then AC is enough because you just move to a larger universe and everything is a set again. If you work with second-order set theory, then this might require things like CC or even DC on a class-level, I don't know enough category theory to give an answer off hand to that sort of question. But then you have to be careful about your statement and formalization into set theory anyway. If you work in ZFC, then global choice should be enough, yes. Because Scott's trick should be enough to reduce the large categories to a locally small collection to choose from.

Comment: Oh right I always forget about Scott's trick ! Yeah in this case global choice is enough, thank you for reminding me of that